# Finding an object from list inside a map

Tags: java

This is my first question in Stackoverflow.I have come to find a issue with one of the problem suggested and give to me by my colleague to do some research on it.

My question is 
i have a class

```
   Class Function{
    String func;
   String funcname;
   boolean log;
   }
```

i have created some objects:

```
 obj1 : ("a" ,"b",true)- //these values come from either DB or UI
obj2 : ("c" ,"x",true)
obj3 : ("a" ,"z",true)
```

i have a list:

```
      List<function> flist;
```

now i want to have that list in the map and want to put in inside the map

```
     Map<String, List<function>> funcMap
```

and then display this following output:

```
    a:[obj1 obj3]
    b:[obj2]
```

if i have the list but how to go about and find the above output as desired

Comment: What have you done so far ?. Show us some code that you've written to achieve this, so that we could help

Comment: i have tried to create a list !! then create another list and add it in another list as list of objects and put it in a map but still the output is not coming as desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

add all the objects in the `flist`.

initialize the map

```
  Map<String, List<Function>> funcMap = new HashMap<String, List<Function>>();
```

going to add the object to the relevant `key` based on the func value the object will add to the value list.

```
  for (Function functionValue : flist)
    {
        List<Function> functionList = funcMap.get(functionValue.getFunc());
        if (functionList != null && !functionList.isEmpty())
        {
            functionList.add(functionValue);
        }
        else
        {
            functionList = new ArrayList<Function>();
            functionList.add(functionValue);
            funcMap.put(functionValue.getFunc(), functionList);
        }
    }
```

Atlast print the funcMap

```
    for (Map.Entry< String, List<Function>> entry : funcMap.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println("Key :  " + entry.getKey() + "Values : "+entry.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. I think it's a case of parsing your list in a nested loop kind of way. Here is the pseudo-code:

```
public void listToMap(List<Function> list)
{
    Map<String, List<Function>> map := new Map
    for every function in the list.
    {
        if(is the current function's func value does not exist in the map)
        {
             func := current functions func value
             List matchingFunctions := new list of Functions.
             for(every function in the list.)
             {
                 // Every Function with the same key get's added to a list.
                 if(function has the same func value as func)
                 {
                     add to matchingFunctions.
                 }
             }

             // That list and key get put into the HashMap.
             map.put(func, matchingFunctions).
        }
    }
}
```

**A Note on your code design**

Java convention states that you should wrap your member objects up in `getters` and `setters`, and that those members should be private.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
public class FuncTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FuncTest().start();

    }

    private void start() {
        List<Function> flist = new ArrayList<Function>();
        flist.add(new Function("a", "b", true));
        flist.add(new Function("c", "x", true));
        flist.add(new Function("a", "z", true));

        Map<String, List<Function>> funcMap = new HashMap<String, List<Function>>();
        for (Function func : flist) {
            this.add(func.func, func, funcMap);
            this.add(func.funcname, func, funcMap);
        }
    }

    private void add(String field, Function func, Map<String, List<Function>> funcMap) {
        List<Function> subList = funcMap.get(field);
        if (subList == null) {
            subList = new ArrayList<Function>();
            funcMap.put(field, subList);
        }

        subList.add(func);
    }
}
```

**Note**

As already mentioned by Chris you should think about your code design. Use `getters` and `setters` ..

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Stackoverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function obj1 = new Function("a" ,"b",true);
        Function obj2 = new Function("c" ,"x",true);
        Function obj3 = new Function("a" ,"z",true);

        List<Function> functionsList1 = new ArrayList<Function>();
        functionsList1.add(obj1);
        functionsList1.add(obj3);

        List<Function> functionsList2 = new ArrayList<Function>();
        functionsList2.add(obj2);

        Map<String, List<Function>> funcMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Function>>();
        funcMap.put("a", functionsList1);
        funcMap.put("b", functionsList2);

        Set<Entry<String,List<Function>>> entrySet = funcMap.entrySet();
        for (Entry<String, List<Function>> entry : entrySet) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

}

class Function {
    String func;
    String funcname;
    boolean log;

    public Function(String func, String funcname, boolean log) {
        super();
        this.func = func;
        this.funcname = funcname;
        this.log = log;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Function [func=" + func + ", funcname=" + funcname + ", log="
                + log + "]";
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi Nagendra !! thank you for your prompt reply!! i have seen this code but what happens is that when you hard code these values it will get really hard to maintain!! i wanted something that can have the values from UI or DB that can be dynamic and can change and grow

Comment: I have given you the pseudo code. Its up to your implementation to decide where the values should come from.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own map. 
Pass the list to map, let map will decide what portion of list to keep as value.
I have added put method here, like the same, have to `Override` other methods.

```
class MyHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V>{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public V put(K k, V v) {
        String key  = (String)k; 
        List<Function> list = (List<Function>) v;
        List<Function> list2 = new ArrayList<Function>();
        for (Function function : list) {
            if(key.equalsIgnoreCase(function.func)){
                list2.add(function);
            }
        }
        return (V) list2;
    };

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // Your own code
       return true;
    }
    // other methods goes here..

}
```